# Which is the first address of ARM DA(Decrement After) addressing mode?

Tags: arm, memory-address, decrement, addressing-mode

I have two questions about DA addressing mode. For example:

```
STMDA R0!, {R1-R7}
```

The start address will be `R0 - (7 * 4) + 4`, that is, `R0-24`, according to the *ARM Architecture reference manual* and end_address will be `R0`.

So:

1. Will the value of `R1` will be stored to `R0-24` or `R0`?
2. If `R1` is stored to `R0-24`, then subsequent stores will grow towards the top of memory (from `R0-24` to `R0`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

part of the pseudocode is shown below:

address = start_address
for i = 0 to 15
if register_list[i] == 1 then
Memory[address,4] = Ri
address = address + 4

it seems that the growth method of STM has nothing to do with addressing mode when storing data?
it always stores data from lower address to higher,the addressing mode only 
decides the start address based on R0?

Answer (score 4):

When using ARM multiple stores and loads, register values are always loaded/stored in ascending order in memory.  So, when using a descending multiple store, the registers are written into memory backwards.  Your `STMDA` instruction effectively breaks down into the following steps:

- store `R7` at `R0`
- store `R6` at `R0 - 4`
- store `R5` at `R0 - 8`
- store `R4` at `R0 - 12`
- store `R3` at `R0 - 16`
- store `R2` at `R0 - 20`
- store `R1` at `R0 - 24`
- subtract 28 from `R0` (because of *writeback* - the `!`).

So, to answer your questions:

1. The value of `R1` will be stored at `R0 - 24`.  (Here, I mean the value of `R0` before executing the instruction, not afterwards.  You're using writeback - the `!` - so after the instruction, `R0` will have had 28 subtracted from it.)
2. `R1` is stored at `R0 - 24`, but as explained above, `R1` is the last register to have its value stored in memory.  `R7` is stored first, and subsequent stores from there grow downwards in memory.

I have to admit I don't know of any documentation that supports this answer.  Also, it's been a while since I last did any ARM coding.  However, I definitely remember wondering how the ARM stores registers in a descending multiple store.  I figured this out by writing a short program to find out.

Comment: +1 absolutely correct.  This behavior is documented in the ARM architecture reference manuals.

Comment: thanks, well, i think the manual defines R0-24 as the start_address is somewhat ambiguous,
this start_address is just the minimum address of the memory instead of the first address that is stored.

Comment: The pseudocode that describes the instruction operation is quite clear, and matches Pourquoi's description.

Answer (score 0):

Search for  arm arm   The ARM Architectural reference manual...

The first address formed is the , and is the value of the base register minus four times the number of registers specified in , plus 4. Subsequent addresses are formed by incrementing the previous address by four. One address is produced for each register that is specified in .